# react js mysql : TypeError: Cannot read property 'affectedRows'

Tags: mysql, node.js, node-modules

I have a error for add distibuteur, can someone help me please for this error.

> c:\users\admin\Desktop\projet-fali\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Parser.js:80 
>       throw err; //Rethrow non-MySQL errors
>       TyepError: Cannot read property 'affectedRows' of undefined at Query._callback

=========================== code ========================

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

//add new distributeur
router.post('/', function(req, res, next) {
    pool.getConnection(function(err, connection) {
        var postBody = req.body;
        var nom = postBody.nom;
        var prenom = postBody.prenom;
        var societe = postBody.societe;
        var adresse = postBody.adresse;
        var siret = postBody.siret;
        var email = postBody.email;
        var tel_fixe = postBody.tel_fixe;
        var tel_mob = postBody.tel_mob;
        var demande= "";
        var code =2;
        connection.query("INSERT INTO admin (nom, prenom, email, tel_fixe, adresse, nsiret, nom_entreprise, demande, code, tel_mob) VALUES ('" + nom + "','" + prenom + "','" + email + "','" + tel_fixe + "','" + adresse + "','" + siret + "','" + societe + "','" + demande + "','" + code + "','" + tel_mob + "')", function(err, rows) {
            if (rows.affectedRows) { // error is in this lign
                connection.query("SELECT * FROM admin WHERE  id='" + rows.insertId + "' LIMIT 1", function(err, rows) {
                    if (!err && rows.length > 0) {
                        res.json(rows[0]);
                    } else {
                        res.json([]);
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    });
});
module.exports = router;
```

I wanted to learn how to handle mysql errors, because my app require mysql.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Just look how you can handle that every query will give you can error or a result as javascript handles error first your first argument in callback will always give you can error and second the result. So you can handle it by using if else conditions.

```
 connection.query("INSERT INTO admin (nom, prenom, email, tel_fixe, adresse, nsiret, nom_entreprise, demande, code, tel_mob) VALUES ('" + nom + "','" + prenom + "','" + email + "','" + tel_fixe + "','" + adresse + "','" + siret + "','" + societe + "','" + demande + "','" + code + "','" + tel_mob + "')", function(err, rows) {
            if (err) {
console.log("===============err====================",err) // error is in this line
}
else{
                connection.query("SELECT * FROM admin WHERE  id='" + rows.insertId + "' LIMIT 1", function(err, rows) {
                    if (!err && rows.length > 0) {
                        res.json(rows[0]);
                    } else {
                        res.json([]);
                    }
                });
            }
        });
```

Comment: When I change the code it shows me this error. error : er_truncated_wrong_value_for_field: incorrect integer value: 'undefined' for column 'ecranlap' at row 1 react js

Comment: Just the the datatype from database it seems like you are entering a string to some value whoes datatype is integer.

Answer (score 0):

Though the question is old, I encountered the same problem and I felt it is required to answer it. It worked for me when I put the parameters of the sql query as follows which is much clear and square brackets is necessary when adding them to the query. Missing the square brackets gives the error not rows.affectedRows.Refer [here](https://www.w3schools.com/nodejs/nodejs_mysql_insert.asp).

```
router.post('/', function(req, res, next) {
    pool.getConnection(function(err, connection) {
        var postBody = req.body;
        var params = [[postBody.nom,postBody.prenom,postBody.societ, postBody.adresse,postBody.siret,postBody.email,postBody.tel_fixe,ostBody.tel_mob,"",2]];
        connection.query("INSERT INTO admin (nom, prenom, email, tel_fixe, adresse, nsiret, nom_entreprise, demande, code, tel_mob) VALUES ?", [params], function(err, rows) {
            if (rows.affectedRows > 0) {
                connection.query("SELECT * FROM admin WHERE  id='" + rows.insertId + "' LIMIT 1", function(err, rows) {
                    if (!err && rows.length > 0) {
                        res.json(rows[0]);
                    } else {
                        res.json([]);
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    });
});
module.exports = router;
```